# convert malloc to new c++ for struct

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc

I have this struct:

```
struct problem
{
int length;
struct node **x;
};
```

and I created a struct of this struct like this:

```
struct problem prob;
```

I can do this in C:

```
prob.x = Malloc(struct node *,prob.length);
```

but how I can do it in c++ style with `new` ?  and why ?

Comment: Show us the code that fails.

Comment: is `Malloc` your own function? `malloc` only works with 1 parameter

Comment: what about `prob.x = new node*[prob.length]`?

Comment: @Manül Given its arguments, `Malloc` must be a macro. Probably something like `#define Malloc(type, cnt) malloc(sizeof(type) * (cnt))`

Comment: "... and why?" Good question. Either keep the code as C, or change it to proper C++, e.g.: `struct problem { std::vector<std::unique_ptr<node>> x; };`

Comment: `#define Malloc(type,n) (type *)malloc((n)*sizeof(type))`

Comment: Put that in the question.

Comment: well i dont want to change the main code, because it is a library that I want to use, but I want to use it with c++

Comment: @user667222 Why do you want to change _this_ code then?  `malloc` works as expected in C++, for situations like this where you are interfacing with legacy code.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, it would be achieved with this.

```
std::vector<node *> problem(length);
```

The code you show is effectively emulating a small subset of the features of `vector`.  Namely, an array-like container that is aware of its size.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this code might work, note that you are no longer holding a pointer to a pointer, but a simple array - which may or may not work for what you are trying to do:

```
typedef struct tagnode
{
  ...
} node;

typedef struct tagproblem
{
int length;
node *x;

tagproblem(int len) : length(len)
 {
  x = new node[length];
 }
~tagproblem()
 {
  delete [] x;
 }
} problem;

//Now create...
problem = new problem(2);
```